# How to combine multiple row into single row based on a particular cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with below format, and it has to be loaded to table

[image]

I have to modify and arrange the column in the below format to load the data into the table. The attached data is sample one and Total I have around 500+ manufactures and 1000+ models.

[image]

I tried merging of rows one by one, but not practical for large data.

Comment: Where would you want to do that change? Source (Excel) or target (Oracle) side? If Oracle, load data *as is* into a temporary table and then apply LISTAGG function to get desired result.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to store it like that - rather than storing it normalised and just aggregating the models for display when needed? What are you going to do if a model is added (or the value changes) - or is this a one-off load of static data?

Comment: @AlexPoole It is only sample data. The actual data is different.

Comment: @Littlefoot I have to do it in excel itself and I think LISTAGG will not work in this case, as the first column is blank for Vitus, Tiguan, Tigun and Beetle for VW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, you can try-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A15,1)),DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A15,1)),LAMBDA(p,q,VSTACK(p,
HSTACK(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B15,SCAN("",A2:A15,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,x)))=q))),
TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(C2:C15,SCAN("",A2:A15,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,x)))=q)))))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then one could use the following formula which is approximately 235 bytes low code, works more swiftly than the any recursive* <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> *helper function.*

Following formula uses <kbd>SCAN( )</kbd> to fill up the empty rows while <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd> helps in joining the `Models` by iterating <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> through <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd>.

<kbd>TEXTBEFORE()</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTAFTER()</kbd> does the finishing job by splitting the `Manufaturer` and `Values` into two columns respectively.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, SCAN(,A2:A20&"|"&C2:C20,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="|",x,y))),
     φ, UNIQUE(α),
     ε, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(φ),1,LAMBDA(x,y,TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTER(B2:B20,INDEX(φ,x)=α)))),
     VSTACK(A1:C1,HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(φ,"|"), ε,TEXTAFTER(φ,"|"))))
```

---

If you don't want the header to return with the output then cut off the `VSTACK(A1:C1` and keep only `HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(φ,"|"), ε,TEXTAFTER(φ,"|"))` at last.

---

However, this task can be more elegantly performed and practically best bet when dealing with large data using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, available in **`Windows Excel 2010+ onwards`** and **`Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)`**

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Modelstbl`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

**Two Methods:** --> Use any one to paste in the <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd>

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Modelstbl"]}[Content],
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(Source,{"Manufacture", "Value"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Manufacture", "Value"}, {{"Models", each Text.Combine([Models]," "), type text}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Manufacture", "Models", "Value"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

---

Or,

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Modelstbl"]}[Content],
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(Source,{"Manufacture", "Value"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Manufacture", "Value"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Manufacture=text, Models=text, Value=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Models", each Table.Column([All],"Models")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Models", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), " "), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"All"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Manufacture", "Models", "Value"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Workbook can be downloaded from **[here...](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckDqIwkF5qwFJQUt0?e=QLMULz)**